# How can I found third 'a' position in the word Malayalam.using sql char index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

Comment: What are you trying to do really? Why using `CHARINDEX()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use CHARINDEX to get the third position of character 'a' as shown below-

This will only return correct result if there are at least 3 existence of character 'a'.

```
DECLARE @Word VARCHAR (100) = 'Malayalam' 
SELECT CHARINDEX('a',@Word,CHARINDEX('a',@Word,CHARINDEX('a',@Word,1)+1)+1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 'Malayalam' s
)
SELECT cte.s, s3.r
FROM cte
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('a', cte.s, 0))      s1(r) -- first occurence
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('a', cte.s, s1.r+1)) s2(r) -- second occurence
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('a', cte.s, s2.r+1)) s3(r) -- third occurence
-- ...
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8e0b2ed4bcdb59e490f492834ea0bdfe)**

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(25) = 'Malayalam';

WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Number + 1 CharPositionInString,
         SUBSTRING(@Str, Number + 1, 1) Character,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(@Str, Number + 1, 1) ORDER BY Number) Occurence
  FROM master..spt_values
  WHERE Type = 'P'
        AND
        Number < LEN(@Str)
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY CharPositionInString;
```

**Returns:**

```
+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
| CharPositionInString | Character | Occurence |
+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
|                    1 | M         |         1 |
|                    2 | a         |         1 |
|                    3 | l         |         1 |
|                    4 | a         |         2 |
|                    5 | y         |         1 |
|                    6 | a         |         3 |
|                    7 | l         |         2 |
|                    8 | a         |         4 |
|                    9 | m         |         2 |
+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
```